# zgrep S3 bucket from script

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-cli

If I want to grep a file from terminal, I can use AWS CLI like this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://path/to/file/filename.tsv.gz - | zgrep 12345
```

I'd like to do this recursively from script. So far I'm doing this

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=prefix + file_name)
body = obj['Body'] 
with gzip.open(body, 'rt') as gf:
    for ln in gf:
        if string in ln:
            print(string)
```

This works fine, but it's actually not really fast. So I'd like to use zgrep instead.

I've tried

```
import subprocess

cp = 'aws s3 cp s3://' + bucket + '/' + prefix + file_name + ' - | zgrep ' + string

result = subprocess.run(cp, check=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result)
```

But get `subprocess.CalledProcessError` as command `returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: You say "it's actually not really fast". Have you investigated whether the time is spent on downloading vs searching? If you are going to be doing multiple searches, it would be more efficient to `sync` the content to your local disk, then `grep` locally. This avoids re-downloading the files each time.

Comment: the script I wrote is to prevent downloading locally. I need to be able to find string directly from bucket as this is just for troubleshooting and there are rather big files and string can be in multiple files.

Comment: But every time you run `aws s3 cp`, it is downloading the file. The output is being sent to `stdout` via the pipe and is then lost. So, the next time you run the command, it is again downloading the file but not saving it to disk. Thus, most of the time is probably being spent downloading the file contents. You will also be paying for Data Transfer each time.

Comment: yes but files are always different so doing it locally would be the same. but at least I don't have to store huge files locally and script creates a file with the occurrences of the string found